# Ray casting on a mesh using libgdx

Tags: software-engineering, libgdx, raycasting

I'm trying to perform ray casting on a mesh using libgdx.

I found [this code sample](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/InteractionWithObjectsIn3D) and it misses some explanations. What do these vectors stand for? What is `globalIntersection` and `localIntersection`?

Answer (score 1):

- globalIntersection is the nearest intersection to the origin of the ray.
- localIntersection is the intersection of a mesh with the ray.

The simplified algorithm is:

```
iterating on the meshes:
    find the intersection of current mesh with ray (localIntersection)
    if intersection is near that globalIntersection:
        update globalIntersection with localIntersection
```